# Retrieve Sql Data Using WebMethod & Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, web-services

I wants to retrieve data from sql server using webserver/jquery and I read many articles but not getting the require matters except below but I think It's support FrameWork .Net 3.5 not 2.0. And I have the same requirement to use it in ASP.Net 2.0.

```
//On WebServer Page..

WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]

public class test : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

 [WebMethod]
 public string GetCustomer(string memberID)
 {
  string response = "<p>No customer selected</p>";
  string connect = "Server=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabase;uid=myuser;pwd=mypassword";
  string query = "SELECT name, father, mother from samaj where name=@memberID";

  if (memberID != null)
  {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
   {
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
   {
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("memberID", memberID);
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (rdr.HasRows)
    {
     while (rdr.Read())
    {
     sb.Append("<p>");
     sb.Append("<strong>" + rdr["name"].ToString() + "</strong><br />");
     sb.Append(rdr["father"].ToString() + "<br />");
     sb.Append(rdr["mother"].ToString() + "<br />");
     response = sb.ToString();
     }
     }
     }
     }
     }
     return response;
     }
     }
     } 
//.aspx page...
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Customers").change(function() 
{ 
 $.ajax
 ({
  type: "POST", 
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
  url: "test.asmx/GetCustomer", 
  data: "{ memberID: '" + $('#Customers').val() + "'}", 
  dataType: "json", 
  success: function(data) 
  { 
   $("#CustomerDetails").html(data.d); 
   } 
   }); 
   }); 
});
</script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="SelectCustomers"> 
<asp:DropDownList ID="Customers" runat="server"> 
</asp:DropDownList> 
</div> 
<div id="CustomerDetails">
</div>
</form>


The DropdownList Binding In Default.aspx.cs page...
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 string connect = "Server=myserver;Initial Catalog=mydatabse;uid=myuser;pwd=mypwd 
 string query = "SELECT name FROM samaj"; 
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connect)) 
 { 
  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) 
 { 
   conn.Open(); 
 Customers.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
 Customers.DataValueField = "name"; 
 Customers.DataBind(); 
 } 
 }
```

.asmx page testing ok It’s retrieves the data well but on client side It’s not return any data. How to achieve it in ASP.Net 2.0?.

Comment: Looks about right... maybe a slight syntax error somewhere. If you debug the app, when you change the item in the #Customers dropdown does any network activity happen? Does it even call the Web Method at all?

Comment: @Ben, no network activity nor Web Method Call?. I didn't saw any activity happen on network.

Comment: In that case there must be a problem with the script - A few things to check: jQuery is loaded, #Customers id is set as expected - if not you need to use $('#<%= Customers.ClientID %>').change(...

Comment: @Ben, I think (data.d) is specially for ASP.Net 3.5 possiblility not to support on ASP.Net 2.0 and I am using ASP.Net 2.0 is n't it?.

Comment: I have already applied $("#<%=Customers.ClientID%>") but no use....

Comment: Have you tried debugging the script? Put a breakpoint inside the event handler and check the change event is being handled?

Comment: put alerts in your onchange function & inside success part of ajax call, in this way also you can check ,which parts of script are executing, also you can add error part after success to see if it is going in error in ajax call.

Comment: you can also try to change  success: function(data)  to something  success: function(testdata) & check